# Nenhum construtor sem parametros foi definido para este objeto

Tags: c#, api, http, controller

Estou criando um endpoint em uma api e ao ser feita uma requisição do método a API retorna o erro "Nenhum construtor sem parâmetros foi definido para este objeto." mesmo tendo sido criado um construtor para isso

```
using Backend.Business;
using Backend.Model;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

    namespace FrontEnd.Controllers
    {
        public class RepliValParamEspfController : Controller
        {
            public OC oc;
            public JavaScriptSerializer serializer;
            public RepliValParamEspfBusiness call;

            public RepliValParamEspfController()
            {
                    this.oc = new OC();
                    this.serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    this.call = new RepliValParamEspfBusiness();
            }
            public object Gravar(RetornaValoresPadroesItens Objs)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (Objs.FilialDestino == null)
                    {
                        this.oc.dados = "Necessario informar Filial Destino!";
                        this.oc.status = true;
                        this.oc.mensagem = "Necessario informar Filial Destino!";
                    }
                    if (Objs.FilialDestino.Equals(String.Empty))
                    {
                        this.oc.dados = "Necessario informar Filial Destino!";
                        this.oc.status = true;
                        this.oc.mensagem = "Necessario informar Filial Destino!";
                    }
                    if (Objs.FilialOrigem == null)
                    {
                        this.oc.dados = "Necessario informar Filial Origem!";
                        this.oc.status = true;
                        this.oc.mensagem = "Necessario informar Filial Origem!";
                    }
                    if (Objs.FilialOrigem.Equals(String.Empty))
                    {
                        this.oc.dados = "Necessario informar Filial Origem!";
                        this.oc.status = true;
                        this.oc.mensagem = "Necessario informar Filial Origem!";
                    }
                    if (Objs.Cpf.Equals(String.Empty))
                    {
                        this.oc.dados = "Necessario informar CPF!";
                        this.oc.status = true;
                        this.oc.mensagem = "Necessario informar CPF!";
                    }
                    if (Objs.Autor.Equals(String.Empty))
                    {
                        this.oc.dados = "Necessario informar Autor!";
                        this.oc.status = true;
                        this.oc.mensagem = "Necessario informar Autor!";
                    }

                    if (this.oc.mensagem == String.Empty)
                    {
                        var response = this.call.Gravar(Objs);
                        this.oc.dados = response;
                        this.oc.status = true;
                        this.oc.mensagem = "Atualizado com sucesso!";
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    this.oc.status = false;
                    this.oc.mensagem = e.Message;
                }
                return serializer.Serialize(this.oc);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Onde dá o erro?

Comment: ele passa pelo public RepliValParamEspfController() , mas não cai no método de Gravar

Comment: ele retorna no postman após passar pelo construtor a mensagem de "Nenhum construtor sem par&#226;metros foi definido para este objeto"

Answer (score 2):

Vai na sua Entidade OC e coloca um cara assim:

```
    public class OC{
...
           public OC(){}
...
    }
```

Comment: consegui resolver o erro dentro da RetornaValoresPadroesItens  eu criei um  public  RetornaValoresPadroesItens() { }

Answer (score 2):

consegui resolver o erro dentro da RetornaValoresPadroesItens 
eu criei o seguinte:

```
   public RetornaValoresPadroesItens() { 

   }
```